# How can i split a overridden method into two in java

Tags: java, class, methods, split, overriding

I'm working on a project and the maintainer suggested me to split a method into two because checks dose not allow to exceed a certain cyclomatic complexity.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Suppression suppression = (Suppression) other;
    return Objects.equals(lineNo, suppression.lineNo)
            && Objects.equals(columnNo, suppression.columnNo)
            && Objects.equals(suppressionType, suppression.suppressionType)
            && Objects.equals(text, suppression.text)
            && Objects.equals(eventSourceRegexp, suppression.eventSourceRegexp)
            && Objects.equals(eventMessageRegexp, suppression.eventMessageRegexp)
            && Objects.equals(eventIdRegexp, suppression.eventIdRegexp)
            && Objects.equals(firstLine, suppression.firstLine)
            && Objects.equals(lastLine, suppression.lastLine);
}
```

this is the overridden equals method and it is exceeding the maximum cyclomatic complexity limit because of the return statements ig.

He suggested splitting it into two, how can I do that.

I'm a beginner so I don't know about java that much, so if this question is completely invalid, then please tell me

Comment: You can move the last part into a method called arePropertiesEqual and call that instead having the comparisons directly in your method. You will gain absolutely nothing except making a maintainer and possibly useless code analysis tool happy.

Comment: I'd reject such bad advice. Your code is clear. If there's a tool telling you to make the code more complex to keep the damn tool happy, turn it off.  Fundamentally, there are 9 fields to compare, so you need 9 comparison terms.

Comment: Which tool is complaining, by the way? (software tool that is)

Comment: @passer-by yes, but that's the last thing we want to do, put this java file in exceptions for that check so that it can exceed the limit by a Lil. but before that, we want to try everything that can reduce the cyclomatic complexity of this method, without creating a mess.

Comment: It depends on your priorities, I suppose: do you want good code, or do you want to obey an arbitrary rule?  That check on that code is completely nonsensical.  I wouldn't go for special casing either; I'd just disable the check.

Comment: @luk2302 that's actually helpful, If I just move all the return statements into some other method, I will reduce the complexity of the current method by 8 I guess.

and it'll keep that useless check happy lmao

but can you help me, how can I actually do this? because statements in the return statement are dependent on the equals method's argument.